# JQuery not responding in Django

Tags: jquery, html, django

I am working on JQuery and Django.

While linking, my JQuery and .css files are linked and accessed through django template but non of the front end tags are recognized.

```
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'groups',value:model.get('name'),id:id1});  
console.log($ctrl);
$("#div1").append($ctrl);
```

This is my code and not even the radio buttons are getting added.
I have linked the media files in settings.py and also configured the urls.py file hence on access the terminal shows a success 200 message to JQuery but nothing beyond that works!

Comment: Are you putting your jquery code inside `$(document).ready()`?

Comment: is jQuery loaded correctly? try `typeof($)` in browser console. it should return 'function'

Comment: What is the purpose of the last line?

Comment: to typeof($) it replies undefined

Comment: @user1871913 - that means jquery is not loaded properly

Comment: but django servers replies a 200 i.e. success msg to the jquery request...

Comment: did you run it from the browser console or from you script? (btw, if you don't prepend you comment with the name of the person like so: @ftom, the person you're referring to won't know you posted a comment)

Comment: and it works fine on standalone but aftr integration with django it fails to load the radio buttons

Comment: I ran it from browser url request...

Comment: after the html is loaded try to view it source and make sure you hav a div with `id="div1"`

Answer (score 3):

Before you can start working on the dom, you have to make sure the dom was loaded. In order to do that you have 2 main ways:

1. put the script decleration at the end of the HTML document right before the closing body tag, that way you know the html has been loaded before your script is running.
2. Use [$(document).ready()](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials%3aIntroducing_%24%28document%29.ready%28%29), that way, your code will start running only after the entire DOM was loaded.

So in your case:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
var $ctrl = $('<input/>').attr({ type: 'radio', name:'groups',value:model.get('name'),id:id1});  
console.log($ctrl);
$("#div1").append($ctrl);


$('<div/>') // create div
});
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, jQuery library is not being loaded when you are serving jquery with django. My suggestion is to use :

```
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.8.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

It will load jquery library online and hope it'll work fine.